# REST API call gives response code 0

Tags: javascript, rest, api

I'm doing an API call to the Insightly API using this code:

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open("GET", "https://api.insight.ly/v2.2/Projects/Search?status=in%20progress&brief=false&count_total=false", true);
x.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic: 'some-basic-key-and-user');
x.send();

console.log(x.status);
```

but the responsecode output equals 0

I've tried my URL and AuthKey using [hurl.it](https://www.hurl.it)'s tool, and it gives back exactly the response I need. I've also tried `x.statusText` and `x.Response`

How come my script doesn't give me the output I need?

**EDIT:**

After trying adding those parameters from Mozilla's documentation (thank you Amy). I still don't get the correct response code.

My code now:

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open("GET", "https://api.insight.ly/v2.2/Projects/Search?status=in%20progress&brief=false&count_total=false", true);
x.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic: b4c6c660-e20f-4f31-b90d-b6a11bfe4ef2');


x.onprogress = function () {
  console.log('LOADING', x.status);
};
x.onload = function () {
  console.log('DONE', x.status);
};

x.send();

console.log(x.status);
```

The response code:

```
0
LOADING 0
```

Also I've read through the possible answer, and I still don't know how to fix my mistake, I know why it is asynchronous and why it doesn't work this way, but I don't know how to fix.

Comment: You're ignoring the asynchronous nature of `XMLHttpRequest` and attempting to examine the status before it has completed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: "Before the request is complete, the value of status will be 0. It is worth noting that browsers report a status of 0 in case of XMLHttpRequest errors too."   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/status

Comment: Add an event handler for the `error` event.  Also look in your browsers dev tools, Network tab.  You might be running into CORS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have unnecessary quote symbol on row 3 (right after some-basic-key-and-user).
Second is that insight api doesn't support cross origin resource sharing ([CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) for short).
You might want to introduce some proxy on the same domain you query data from.